# dayjs(...).isLeapYear is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dayjs

**This is my HTML File**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs"></script>
<script type="module" src="node_modules/dayjs/dayjs.min.js">
    import dayjs from 'dayjs'

    dayjs().format();

    import isLeapYear from "dayjs/plugin/isLeapYear";
    dayjs.extend(isLeapYear);
</script>
```

**This is my JavaScript**

```
const leapCheck = () => {
    const leapInputYear = dayjs(inputYear).isLeapYear();
    const leapCurrentYear = dayjs(currentYear).isLeapYear();
};
```

I tried follow the documentation from dayjs() to check whether the year is a leap year and I can't seem to grasp the actual problem there.

Comment: it's because ```isLeapYear``` is undefined

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are not loading the plugin properly, to load a dayjs plugin in the browser you need to use the window object. https://dayjs.gitee.io/docs/en/plugin/loading-into-browser

```
<!-- CDN example (jsDelivr) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script>dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc)</script>
```

```js
 // load the isLeapYear plugin
 dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_isLeapYear);


console.log(dayjs('2000-01-01').isLeapYear())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/isLeapYear.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="node_modules/dayjs/dayjs.min.js">
    import dayjs from 'dayjs'

    dayjs().format();

</script>
```